# Win10 (21H1) regular BSOD - memory management

Tags: windows-10, bsod, memory-management

Regular BSOD on address ntoskrnl.exe+3f71b0 in random app

Notebook — ASUS ROG STRIX SCAR II GL504GS ES125T

1. SDD test — ok
2. Memory test — ok
3. Last BIOS update installed
4. Last win udates installed
5. Last drivers on devices installed
6. sfc /scannow — ok
7. chkdsk c: /F /R — ok

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xanma6s8r5iapel/21H1-BSOD-history.pdf
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0n3xbp281dwqgp/21H1_CrashDumps.zip

Very annoing. Please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks
it`s no overclocked machine. Cooler is fine, i clean cooling system and monitoring cpu temp. I think is not hardware error, because after reinstall win, the problem has not appear during 2 month.

Comment: I am pretty sure that ntoskrnl.exe+3f71b0 refers to the place in the kernel that contains the MiDereferenceIoPages function (I debugged your logs).  That function fails to access memory and issues an "int 3" (debug break) which causes BSOD when not running a checked build of windows.  `Probably caused by : memory_corruption ( nt!MiDereferenceIoPages+13fc12 )` is one of the many things WinDbg shows me.  In theory, it could be the pagefile or a device driver for the memory controller too making this problem really suck. :(

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas oh, thanks for research...

Comment: доброе утро!  Sometimes, changes to the kernel can expose parts of the hardware that weren't being used before.  I am not saying that is what happened with the update but I AM saying that millions of people are running this update without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run a complete set of Hardware Tests from the ASUS support site.  Also run several passes of Memtest86.exe (https://www.memtest86.com/).

When done and given your other tests, run a Windows 10 Repair Install and begin with the option to Keep Everything.

Full instructions and all options follow:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation

Comment: Thanks, i try it.

Comment: If, after all the above, it is also possible you have a hardware error (memory).

Comment: Is it possible to be a hardware error if memory test is ok and error is always on address "ntoskrnl.exe+3f71b0" ?

Comment: That is possible. Your post inferred all was well until you updated to V21H1.